# Expectations using Indicator Functions

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

Consider the following problem. a, b are constants in [0,1] and x is a random variable drawn from a continuous distribution F with support on [0,1]. Let $1_m$ represent the indicator function associated to the event m.

I want to calculate the following:

$E_x [(a-x) 1_{(b<x<a)}]$

Which I believe is of the form:

$\int_b^a (a- x) f(x)$ $dx$

But I do not know if this is true or how to get the solution. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: If $f$ denotes the PDF then this is true. If $f$ is known to you then in principle you can calculate this integral in order to "get the solution".

Comment: f  is indeed the pdf. But imagine it is a uniform pdf on [0,1]. Should I use the f with the new boundaries, i.e. 1/(a-b) or just the unrestricted ones 1/(1-0) ? I computed the integral with the initial support and got $\frac{a^2}{2}-ab+\frac{b^2}{2}$. Does that look good?

Comment: Yes that looks okay. You must indeed use the original PDF. The adjusted PDF comes into picture if you want the distribution of $x$ "under **condition** of $b<x<a$". That is not the case here.